# saveFrame can't keep up with frameRate in processing

Tags: processing, frame-rate, processing.js

I am using saveFrame to create an image sequence to bring into after effects. At each loop, I'm upping the frameRate - which I'm sure is not the best way to go about thing. At the end of each loop, I'm saving the frame, but saveFrame can't keep up with the progressively higher frameRate I'm trying to save at. Anyone have an idea how to achieve the effect I'm going for without upping the frameRate, so that saveFrame can keep up? Here's my code:

````
```
int w = 640; // canvas size
int h = 480;
int n = 10;  // number of grid cells
int d = w/n; // diameter of a grid cell
float depth = 0.5; // relative cell depth
int fr = 100;

int iterator = 0;

boolean doSaveFrames = false;

void setup() {
  size(w, h, P3D);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  background(0);
  fill(51, 255, 0);
  noStroke();
  frameRate(fr);
}

void draw() {

  // get coordinates
  int xy = frameCount % (n*n);

  // shift image in z-direction
  if (xy == 0) {
    PImage img = get();
    background(0); 
    pushMatrix(); 
    translate(0, 0, -d * depth);
    tint(255, 127);
    image(img, 0, 0);
    popMatrix();

//    fr+=iterator*10;
//    frameRate(fr); //MH - really cool but I can't export fast enough
    iterator++;

  }

  // scale and rotate the square
  scale(d);
  translate(xy%n + .5, xy/n + .5, -depth * .5 );
  rotate(QUARTER_PI - HALF_PI *int(random(2)));
  rotateX(HALF_PI);

  // draw the square
  rect(0, 0, sqrt(2), depth);

  if (doSaveFrames) {
    saveFrame("frames/line-######.tga");
  }

}
```
````

Comment: can you explain *why* you're upping the framerate? Because that just speeds up the animation more and more every time you save, which doesn't really make any sense...

Comment: Yeah - I don't want to speed up the rate for each save, I want to speed up the overall animation and have the saveFrame actually capture that increase in speed - I suppose one way to solve it would be to save every nth-frame, increasing in duration each cycle.

Comment: I don't follow, and that might be because of terminology: a frame, in Processing terms, is the graphics state between the start and end of the `draw()` method, and the `frameRate` determined how often `draw` is called per second. You can speed up the animation by increasing the `frameRate` value, but you can't capture any "increase in speed" in single frames... individual frames have no speed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of basing your animation off of the `frameCount` variable, create your own variable that you increment at your own speed, and then increase that speed over time. Keep your framerate the same, but increase your animation speed.